# No sound in Crouton

Tags: sound, chromebook, crouton

I'm using a Chromebook and I've installed Ubuntu on it with Crouton...
My sound is fine when I'm in my Chrome OS but I have no sound at all when I'm in Ubuntu. Uhhhh... what do you think?

Answer (score 5):

I too faced this issue. The below steps solved the issue.

First remove pulseaudio and alsa-base packages:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge pulseaudio alsa-base
```

Now  re-install alsa-base:

```
sudo apt-get install alsa-base
```

Logout from Ubuntu and log in again...

Comment: One question - this fixes sound, but the indicator-sound-gtk2 package depends on pulseaudio, so removing pulseaudio removes the sound indicator. Is there any way you know of to get indicator-sound-gtk2 back, or to fix the sound without removing pulseaudio?

Comment: This didn't work for me on Ubuntu/saucy running on an SD Card (i.e. without crouton.  It was a chrubuntu install, now its basically a plain Ubuntu install).

Comment: It really helps, but indeed removes sound indicator. It is fine until I'm not using any sound in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer on the [Debian wiki page about the Samsung Chromebook](https://wiki.debian.org/InstallingDebianOn/Samsung/ARMChromebook).  There were two things I had to do on my Samsung Chromebook 5 running Ubuntu/saucy.  In Ubuntu, I've mounted the ChromeOS system on `/media/root-a`.

1. copy some alsa support files from Chrome: `cp /media/root-a/usr/share/alsa/ucm/DAISY-I2S/HiFi.conf /usr/share/alsa/ucm/DAISY-I2S`
2. edit `/etc/pulse/default.pa` to add this line: `load-module module-alsa-sink device=sysdefault`

Then I rebooted and I had working audio!